# можно ли тело конструктора вынести за пределы прототипа класса подобно функции?

Tags: c++

Имеется довольно большой конструктор и хочется его вынести за пределы определения класса оставив только прототип, подобно функции, но как это правильно сделать? Вот сам конструктор:

```
truth_table(std::size_t column = min_value) : column(column)
{
    string = pow(bi, column);
    rezult.resize(string, 0);
    tabl.resize(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabl.size(); ++i) {
        tabl[i].resize(column, 0);
    }

    std::vector<bool> mask(column, 0);
    mask[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < mask.size(); ++i) {
        mask[i] = mask [i - 1] + mask [i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tabl.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tabl[i].size(); ++j) {
            tabl[i][j] = (i & mask[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычный способ не помогает?

Comment: какой обычный способ?

Comment: а как вы обычно объявляете функции-члены?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и любую функцию-член:

```
class Type ...
{
   ...
   Type(...);


...

Type::Type(...):base(...)
{
    ....
}
```

Да, значения по умолчанию оставьте в объявлении конструктора, в определении их использовать не нужно.

Comment: без указания какого-либо возвращаемого значения, типа `void`?

Comment: Да. Конструктор ничего не возвращает.

Comment: окей, а если перед конструктором указан `explict` его указываем только в протипе в классе?

Comment: Да. Он не входит в сигнатуру.

Comment: спасибо, вроде все понял